# Find next record in sorted TDBGrid

Tags: sorting, delphi, dbgrid

I have TDBGrid on witch I have connected FDQuery. I sort records on fly with  use of FDQuery indexes when column title is clicked.

```
procedure TMainDM.CreateIndexes(AQuery: TFDQuery);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  try
    AQuery.Indexes.Clear;
    for I := 0 to AQuery.FieldCount - 1 do
    begin
      with AQuery.Indexes.Add do
      begin
        Name := AQuery.Fields[i].FieldName + '_index_asc';
        Fields:= AQuery.Fields[i].FieldName;
        Options:= [soNoCase];
        Active:= True;
      end;
      with AQuery.Indexes.Add do
      begin
        Name := AQuery.Fields[i].FieldName + '_index_desc';
        DescFields:= AQuery.Fields[i].FieldName;
        Fields:= AQuery.Fields[i].FieldName;
        Active:= True;
      end;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ErrorLogger('ERROR: TMainDM.CreateIndexes -> ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

How would  I get next record from currently selected? I know that I move to next record of unsorted grid with this:

```
DBGrid.DataSource.Dataset.Next;
```

I know that I move to next record in filtered grid with this:

```
DBGrid.DataSource.Dataset.FindNext;
```

How can I find next record in sorted list? When I call Next or FindNext I get next record of unsorted grid.

### **EDIT 1**

I had FDQuery property IndexName set to index selected in event OnColumnSort.

```
if Direction then
  TFDQuery(TaskDataSource.DataSet).IndexName:= Column.FieldName + '_index_asc'
else
  TFDQuery(TaskDataSource.DataSet).IndexName:= Column.FieldName + '_index_desc';
```

I get result described above. In first code block I create indexes for all fields so they are ready to be called in seconde code block (event OnColumnSort)

### **EDIT 2**

I've changed some code. I put index creation in the event OnColumnSort so there isn't index for every field on start. Query.Next still doesn't work.

```
procedure TMain.TaskGridColumnSort(Column: TUniDBGridColumn;
  Direction: Boolean);
begin
  try
    TFDQuery(TaskDataSource.DataSet).Indexes.Clear;
    if Direction then
    begin
      with TFDQuery(TaskDataSource.DataSet).Indexes.Add do
      begin
        Name := Column.FieldName + '_index_asc';
        Fields:= Column.FieldName;
        Options:= [soNoCase];
        Active:= True;
      end;
      TFDQuery(TaskDataSource.DataSet).IndexName:= Column.FieldName + '_index_asc';
    end
    else
    begin
      with TFDQuery(TaskDataSource.DataSet).Indexes.Add do
      begin
        Name := Column.FieldName + '_index_desc';
        DescFields:= Column.FieldName;
        Fields:= Column.FieldName;
        //Options:= [soDescending, soNoCase];
        Active:= True;
      end;
      TFDQuery(TaskDataSource.DataSet).IndexName:= Column.FieldName + '_index_desc';
    end;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      MainDM.ErrorLogger('ERROR: TMain.TaskGridColumnSort -> ' + E.Message);
  end;
```

end;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINAL EDIT**

I found the problem. Problem was in closing and reopening dataset. So sort (index)  lost in Refresh. I solve problem with remembering my index name before I Close dataset and place it back when i Open dataset.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be having the same problem as this q:

[Indexes don't work in FDQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161974/indexes-dont-work-in-fdquery)

What you need to do is to add the line

```
AQuery1.IndexName := AIndex.Name;
```

as the last line before your `except` block.

Btw, the sorting is nothing to do with the grid, of course.  Once the index is properly 
active, the grid will display in the correct order and calls to `AQuery.Next` should behave as expected.

Comment: I do suggested in event OnColumnSort. I get sorted grid but Query.Next behavior is still the same. Look my Edit.